# Blank parent form if subform has no data

Tags: ms-access, vba

i have my regular form with a continous form attached to it. Everything works fine untill the subform has no data.
Here is the subform with data
image1 [image]

IF there are no data in the subform, the form becomes like this.
image 2 [image]

I am using the following code in my on current event on my main form:

```
Function RefreshCOunt()
If Me.frmVerifyEquipmentSub.Form.Recordset.RecordCount = 0 Then

    Me.frmVerifyEquipmentSub.Visible = False
    Me.txtTotal = 0
    Me.Refresh

Else
    Me.frmVerifyEquipmentSub.Visible = True
    Me.frmVerifyEquipmentSub.Form.Requery
    Forms![test3].txtTotal = Me.frmVerifyEquipmentSub.Form.txtSum
    Me.Refresh
    Forms![test3].Refresh

End If
End Function

Private Sub Form_Current()
Call RefreshCOunt
End Sub

Private Sub Form_GotFocus()
Call RefreshCOunt
End Sub
```

Here is the code on my subform, THis function is run when my user clicks the save button.

```
Function RefreshCOunt()
If Me.txtCount = 0 Then
    Forms![test3].SetFocus
Else
    Me.Requery
    Forms![test3].txtTotal = Me.txtSum
    Me.Refresh
    Forms![test3].Refresh

End If
End Function
```

I have a text behind the subform which says "NO Available Data to be shown"

2 problems in this situation are:

1. Empty form view as shown on image 2 (resolved as i had linked the record source of the main form to the table also used in subform)
2. Hide the subform once the user has verified all the equipment.
   -currently my code only works the first time the form is loaded.
   -the subform does not hide once the user has verifed all the equipment

I know how to do this in report with the HAsData function but i am not sure how i can do so in Forms.

Comment: Do the forms have a proper Child/Parent relationship?  If they do, the parent form should be independent of whether or not data is returned on the child form, so those fields should populate no matter what.

Comment: i just realised that i had my main form linked to a record source that is the same as the subform which caused the problem

Comment: That'll do it every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your query for the main form has an inner join to the table (or a query with this table) for the subform.

Remove this join or change it to an outer join.

Comment: oh yes! i didnt realise my main form has it record source linked to the same table as the subform. Now that i removed record source from my main form. it works

Comment: There's actually a second part which is to hide the subform if there is no data. Currently, it does not hide the subform when the user has verified all the records. i will edit my post

Comment: I managed to solve this Issue by setting the focus back to the main form and running the refresh count function